# C# populating combo boxes with 2 columns

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access-2010

I'm currently populating a combobox with a value from one column from an Access database, of which I want to get its corresponding primary key value to use later on in my program.

For example: Two columns in the table such as  ID(PK) and Title

Populating the combobox with Title, how can I get its corresponding ID value?

My only thought  would be to create and run another query just to get the id where the other column value matches, but this just seems an inefficient way to go about this.

From my understanding and reading around this isn't easily possible, but any suggestions on how I may overcome this would be gratefully appreciated!

What I have so far using winforms

```
      private void populateBox()
    {
        oleDbConnectionDARS.Open();
        dr = oleDbCommandTitle.ExecuteReader();
        comboBoxTitle.Items.Clear();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBoxTitle.Items.Add(dr["Title"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        oleDbConnectionDARS.Close();
    }



   **SELECT        titleID, Title
   FROM            tbl_Book**
```

Comment: What are you doing this in? ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone.... ? Show code of how you're binding the combo box now, and we can show you how to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you've posted, you're not using data binding - and instead just manually adding them in a loop.

You should look at using DataBinding - [Example for Binding a Windows Forms ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx)

If instead you wish to continue using the current method, then you can use the Tag property on ComboBoxItem to store data you wish to use.

eg:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
   comboBoxTitle.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Name = dr["Title"], Tag = dr["titleID"]});
}
```

To access the value at a later time, simply look at the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem_properties.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up two properties of the ComboBox. 
DisplayMember should be the displaying value that you´ll show to the user.
ValueMember should be the value of the ID in your database.

This works for System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox class

Comment: Viewing your example, you can add the results of your query to a DataTable, and then set the DataSource property of your combo to the resulting DataTable

Comment: Using display member and value member is fine, but if they change their selection it remains fixed to the previous selection.

Comment: How is that?. you can access the SelectedValue, and SelectedText to determine the properties of the selection